# Visitor variant with multiple types (string, bool, integral, float)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to use a variant's visitor for multiple types and then generating a new random value. Be aware that I can't use more recent compiler than Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and GCC 4.9 because of reasons out of my control.

Here is what I have

```
std::random_device randomDevice;
std::mt19937 randomEngine(randomDevice());

typedef mpark::variant<     // Implementation of std::variant for C++11,14
    bool,
    int8_t, uint8_t,
    int16_t, uint16_t,
    int32_t, uint32_t,
    int64_t, uint64_t,
    float, double,
    std::string
> VariantValue;

struct ValueVisitor
{
    ValueVisitor(VariantValue* pNewVal)
      : pNewVal(pNewVal) {}

    void operator()(const std::string & s) const
    {
      // Generate some random string into *pNewVal
    }

    void operator()(const bool& t) const
    {
        *pNewVal = !t;
    }

    template <typename T,
      std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr,
      std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value>* = nullptr>
    >
        void operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T> dist
        (
            std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest(),
            std::numeric_limits<T>::max()
        );

        *pNewVal = dist(randomEngine);
    }

    template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
        void operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist
        (
            std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest(),
            std::numeric_limits<T>::max()
        );

        *pNewVal = dist(randomEngine);
    }

    VariantValue* pNewVal;
};

VariantValue vSource {(double)12 };
VariantValue vTarget;

ValueVisitor valueVisitor(&vTarget);
mpark::visite(valueVisitor, v);
```

But I'm getting the error `C2338 invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution`.

Looking at output window for more details

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\random(2387): error C2338: invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution
1>  d:\project\xxx.cpp(271): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::uniform_int_distribution<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int8_t
1>          ]
1>  d:\project\3rdparty\mpark\include\mpark\lib.hpp(237): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void ValueVisitor::operator ()<T,void>(const T &) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int8_t
1>          ]
...
```

So, If I well understood, it seems that when `T=bool` the functor's function targeted is the one for `is_integral`. But why ? I explicitly removed the bool type with `std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value>* = nullptr`.

I tried a different approaches like

```
template <typename T>
void operator()(const T & t)
{
    if (std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
    } else if (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
    } else if (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
    } else if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value) {
}
```

But without success, it's worst as now the float variation are still trying to use the `uniform_int_distribution`.

I'm really out of idea.

Best regards,

Comment: Once typo fixed, works as expected with std::variant of C++17 [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d6f41ecd091b57e).

Comment: A friend tried this code on GCC and this is compiling successfully, but on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 I'm still getting the same error `invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution`. Sorry I didn't saw your `demo` link. I'm looking into it right now. Do you tried with VS 2015 ?

Comment: @Jarod42, I tried your demo on Visual Studio 2015 but I'm getting the same error `invalid template argument for uniform_int_distribution`. Could it be a bug from VS ?

Comment: Cannot test on VS 2015, but try `typename std::enable_if<>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<>`. As I remember, VS has a bug about that for SFINAE.

Comment: @Jarod42, I replace with `std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr, std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value>* = nullptr` but now I'm getting `fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\cxx\dymto.c', line 21013)`.

Comment: @Jarod42, I found something else interesting. If I removed the `int8_t and uint8_t` from the variant, the compilation succeed. Like the  `uniform_int_distribution` (version of Visual Studio) do not accept T as `int8_t`. But on GCC there no problem.